# How to create a bubble sort for a doubly linked list with a swap function?

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to figure out how to write a member function for DNode called `DNode *DNode::bubble()` for a
   `DNode *head` which can bubble-sort the linked list and return the new head.
   I want to use a member function `void swap(DNode *that)`
   to swap two nodes.

Here's what I have so far regarding the .h and .cpp files:

```
#ifndef DNODE_H
#define DNODE_H
class DNode {

public:

int key;
DNode *next;
DNode *prev;

void add(int key);
void print();
DNode();
DNode *bubble();
void swap(Dnode *that);
};

#endif

#include "DNode.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void DNode::swap(DNode *that){
DNode *temp = this;
DNode *R1, *L1, *R2, *L2;

}

Dnode *Dnode::bubble(){
DNode *temp = this;
int count = 0;
while(start != NULL){
count++;
start = start->next;
}

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

}
}
```

What I'm having a problem with is the swap function to swap the nodes in the list with just that one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Well all you need to do is adjust the `next` and `prev` members of both, as well as sync up the links from previous & next elements of those:

```
void DNode::swap(DNode *that) 
{
  // this->prev->next points back to 'this' should become 'that'
  if(this->prev) {
    this->prev->next = that;
  }
  // this->next->prev points back to 'this' should become 'that'
  if(this->next) {
    this->next->prev = that;
  }
  // that->prev->next points back to 'that' should become 'this'
  if(that->prev) {
     that->prev->next = this;
  }
  // that->next->prev points back to 'that' should become 'this'
  if(that->next) {
     that->next->prev = this; 
  }
  // remember whatever 'this' ->next and ->prev point to
  DNode * n1 = this->next, * p1 = this->prev;
  // let 'this' take the position of 'that in the list
  this->prev = that->prev;
  this->next = that->next;
  // let 'that' take the position of the original 'this' in the list.
  that->prev = p1;
  that->next = n1;
}
```

Alternatively: if you simply want to swap *values* at a particular logical position in the list then you can also simply exchange the values:

```
void swap(DNode* that)
{
  int old = this->key;
  this->key = that->key;
  that->key = old;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to swap the key values between the 2 nodes, but this also should not be a big problem.  
`int temp = this.key;  this.key=that->key; that->key=temp;`

Comment: @GeriPapi that is not necessary: it's the links which determine position in the list layout. Of course, you could take the opposite view: simply swap keys and don't bother. It depends if memory layout of the list node matters.

Comment: How would I place swap into my bubble sort function? @user268396

Comment: You should create a `static` bubble member function. In your loop you need to iterate in a particular direction over the nodes of the list and take list boundaries into account. The swap member function takes the same place as the swap operation in normal bubble sort of an array, with the left or right hand operand being the this object the swap() function is called on (left for forwards iteration, right for backwards).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to possibly put a code example here? It's just this is still confusing.